# Is it possible to publish a gmail addon to the marketplace for free?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-apps-marketplace

I was wondering how do i publish a gmail add-on to the google marketplace?

I already created an add-on in apps scrips and connected it to google cloud platform project, but when i filled out the OAuth consent screen I got an email that said since I'm using some restricted scopes I need to go through a verification that can cost between 8k-75k dollars.

Is that really necessary to be able to publish an add-on to the marketplace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**According to the [OAuth API verification FAQs documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en):**

> Some of the scopes used by the following APIs are considered sensitive; see the API’s documentation or look for the lock icon in the Cloud Console. If your app requests sensitive scopes, and doesn’t meet any of the criteria for an exception (see below), you will need to verify that your app follows the API Services User Data Policy.

Therefore, if your add-on is using **any** of the scopes listed [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#sensitive-scopes), you **do have** to go through the verification process.

There are also exceptions to the verification process; specifically for the add-on you are mentioning, these might apply:

1. If you want to deploy the add-on solely for **internal use** which means that the add on will be used only by people in your Google Workspace or Cloud Identity organization.
2. If you want to use the add-on **domain wide** which means that the add on will be used only by Google Workspace enterprise users within the domain.

For the whole list of exceptions, you can check this [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#exceptions-ver-reqts).

#### Reference

- [OAuth API verification FAQs](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).

Comment: So the verification if needed will cost some of that amount i listed above?

Comment: Yes, you can read more about it in the *Verification process* > *What are the requirements for verification?* from the documentation I shared above. @JakubMichálek